# Zoomable D3 Angular Treemap Directive

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I cannot seem to find a reusable D3 Angular Treemap Directive that zooms like Mike Bostock's [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/).  If anyone has created one in the past or can give me any information pertaining to where I could find one I would be very greatful!

Heck, it doesn't absolutely have to be D3 either, I just need to get this working in an angular project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a div like this in html here we will hook our treemap:

```
<div linear-chart></div>
```

Next make a directive to map the linear-chart attribute:

```
app.directive('linearChart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var root = scope.data;
      //here you make your svg to the elem
      var svg = d3.select(elem[0]).append("svg")
      //tree map code
    }
```

Inside the link function you can copy the [example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) code, such that you hook the tree map to the element as shown above.

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h0q6xb45/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The most useful solution so far! It should be included in 'nvd3-angular'.